# pandas profiling import error : not able to import pandas_profiling package

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-profiling, exploratory-data-analysis

I cannot import name `DataError` from `pandas.core.base`

When I import package:

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

it shows error:

```
cannot import name 'DataError' from 'pandas.core.base'
```

Comment: Typo in ProfileRreport

Comment: What versions of pandas and pandas-profiling are you using?

Comment: pandas   1.5.1
pandas-profiling  3.2.0

Comment: what bugs me is that it installs fine, but just can't be imported

Answer (score 2):

The new version of Python (3.11) does not work with `pandas_profiling`. However, the old version works fine.

My version is `3.8.8`, and it works in the command line:

```py
import pandas_profiling as pp  
data = pd.read_csv( "-----.csv")
pp.ProfileReport(data)
```